# How to determine a DC for a magical effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, gm-techniques, difficulty-class

The DC guidelines in the DMG are in increments of five (DC 15 for a moderate task, DC 20 for a hard one, etc.). Yet, a lot of spells and magic items use DCs like 13 or 17.

Are there any guidelines, apart from "assign the DC that feels right", to decide what specific DC is appropriate (usually these are saving throw DCs)?

Comment: Are you creating magic items or monsters?

Comment: Right now I'm mostly concerned about spells for monsters.